# delete all lines from a file using string from another file with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a file1:

```
hello
world
```

And file2:

```
hello   A
hello   X
world   B
byebye  C
```

And I want to delete all lines that match the string in file1 from file2, to get this output:

```
byebye C
```

I am a beginner programming so I could only come up with this:

```
for i in {1..2}  
do  p=`sed -n ${i}p file1`  
sed '/$p\t\w/d' file2 > file2.tmp && mv file.tmp file2
done
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If someone could explain me why my little script didn't work I would really appreciate that. :)

Comment: You are using single quote in sed command so sed treated as `$p` like  literal `$p` not `hello` or `word`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this grep command

```
grep -vf  file1 file2 > file2
```

Your coding:

```
for i in {1..2}
do
p=`sed -n ${i}p file1`
sed -i "/^$p/d" file2
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($1 in a)' f1 f2
byebye  C
```

Using `grep -vf`

```
grep -vFf f1 f2
byebye  C
```

Answer (score 1):

Why didnt you code work

- `sed` does not understand  `\w`

  **solution** use `-r` flag for extended regex
- `'/$p\t\w/d'` the variables are not expanded in single quotes

  **solution** use double quotes instead

**Corrected**

```
$for i in {1..2}  ; 
do 
p=`sed -n ${i}p file1`
sed -r "/$p\t\w/d" file2 > file2.tmp && mv file2.tmp file2
done
$ cat file2
byebye  C
```

This will provide output as

```
byebye  C
```

**Note**

Offcourse this provides the expected output, But there is always some other easy ways of accomplishing the task as in other answers